# The "Allow anyway" button on the "... was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer" does not appear

Tags: ventura

[image]

I have selected "App store an identified developers" in the security setting

there is supposed to be an "Allow Anyway" button that appears when I try to open the non-identified app.

However, this button does not appear. See the modal side-by-side with the setting from the settings panel

Comment: What do you see if you right-click > Open ?

Comment: The same result: A message saying the app is blocked and offering my only "Cancel" and "Move to Trash". Despite all of the online docs saying that right-click to open will bypass the security quarantine, this appears not to be true any longer for Ventura.

Comment: Where did you download the application from? Providing a link might help others to check for themselves what might be wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only known fix that I have found to this problem is to run this special command to de-quarantine the app

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ for\ Testing.app/`

update 2024-02-02
macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 now tells me :
`xattr: /Applications/Google Chrome for Testing.app/: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine`

however, the actual bug (the absence of the "Allow anyway" button) appears to be fixed in the OS

Comment: my sonoma 14.1.2 is now saying`xattr: /Applications/Google Chrome for Testing.app/: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine`

Answer (score 2):

MacOS flags the "This app is damaged" alert when the digital signature is invalid. This is usually the case if the file has been modified in some way after signing; but it could also be an issue with the certificate used to sign the app. (E.g. expired, pulled.)

You should try re-downloading the app; and if that fails, contact the developers.

This is a different issue from a quarantine flag, which usually just alerts the user that the app has recently been downloaded and is from an unknown developer: but you are normally still given the possibility to open it.

If deleting the quarantine flag did indeed fix it, then it could well be a bug, and you should report it to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the "Google Chrome for Testing" file is damaged, so it can't be opened. It is not being blocked by security, but the file is corrupted. To un-corrupt the file, I would recommend to re-install the application.